# Why should controllers use notify_airbrake over Airbrake.notify

Tags: ruby-on-rails, airbrake

In the [Airbrake wiki](https://github.com/airbrake/airbrake/wiki/Sending-notices-to-Airbrake-manually-from-controllers), it says to use `notify_airbrake` in controllers instead of `Airbrake.notify`, but doesn't explain why. What is the benefit of using `notify_airbrake` in controllers and why should it not be used elsewhere?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`notify_airbrake`](https://github.com/airbrake/airbrake/blob/68bec4972aa3bbc75014f8f67ea7ea5213b0a02c/lib/airbrake/rails/controller_methods.rb#L29-L35) is just a helper method. You don't have to use it (feel free to use `Airbrake.notify`). However `notify_airbrake` attaches [extra information](https://github.com/airbrake/airbrake/blob/68bec4972aa3bbc75014f8f67ea7ea5213b0a02c/lib/airbrake/rails/controller_methods.rb#L7-L17) to the notice (like current user, session, Rack environment, etc). With `Airbrake.notify` you will only send what you pass to the method.

Answer (score 1):

This is the beauty of open source. You can look at the code and figure out how and why something is implemented the way it is.

Having said that, look at airbrake code, specifically `controller_methods.rb` file (https://github.com/airbrake/airbrake/blob/3033798f69d20706f13fc0e3d79572041e9c7205/lib/airbrake/rails/controller_methods.rb)

You can see that `notify_airbrake` method actually calls a variant of `Airbrake.notify` (`Airbrake.notify_or_ignore`) after it extracts some extra information automatically like session data, request url, request params etc which are only available in the controller context. If they didn't do it this way, we will have to extract that information manually in the controller and pass it along. It's only there to make our lives easier :)

My 2 cents.